# How to configure WebJob ServiceBusTrigger retry policy

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, retrypolicy

**Edit:** I will accept Azure configuration related changes as an answer to this question.

---

I am attempting to setup a retry policy to prevent instantly retrying a message when a 3rd party service is temporarily unavailable.

Currently the job is retried immediately multiple times and fails each time due to the temporary outage of the 3rd party service.

How do I set a retry delay for these messages?

I have the following code for Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();

        config.UseCore();
        config.UseServiceBus(new ServiceBusConfiguration()
        {
            ConnectionString = Configuration.GetAppSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"),
            MessageOptions = new OnMessageOptions()
            {

            }
        });

        var host = new JobHost(config);

        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Information("F1.Birst.Automation web job starting.");
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

I have an ErrorMonitor setup which properly logs errors:

```
public class ExceptionHandler
{
    private static readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public void Handle([ErrorTrigger] TraceFilter message, TextWriter log)
    {
        foreach (var exception in message.GetEvents())
            Log.Error(exception.Exception.InnerException, exception.Message);
    }
}
```

And my message handler looks like this:

```
public class ChurchCodeChangedEventHandler : ChurchSpaceHandler
{
    private static readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public void Handle([ServiceBusTrigger(nameof(ChurchCodeChangedEvent), "F1.Birst.Automation.ChurchCodeChangedEvent")] ChurchCodeChangedEvent message, TextWriter log)
    {
        Log.Information(LogTemplates.ChurchCodeChanged, message.ChurchId);

        // snip
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I set a retry delay for these messages?

Webjobs do not support the concept of delayed retries. You can only control a few things using [`ServiceBusConfiguration`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus), but those are not retries looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/830447f5153ede8253862a22ec5bc1c5fd588232/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Config/ServiceBusConfiguration.cs#L14).

You could use frameworks like [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-delayed-retries) or [MassTransit](http://masstransittemp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/middleware/retry.html) to get delayed retries. There's an example of how to use [NServiceBus with WebJobs](https://docs.particular.net/samples/show-case/cloud-azure/) and you can run it locally to see how delayed retries would work.

Comment: I've used NServiceBus before and love it. Unfortunately it's not an option currently. Talking to our contact at Microsoft, and hoping they have some undocumented solution -_-;.

Comment: You do not want to rely on undocumented solutions. Product Group will never give you such a thing. And if you get it from a Solutions Architect, question it. W/o native support for exact feature you will need to implement it yourself or use something else that does it for you. No magic 